# How does the intensity of electromagnetic signals change with angular height of a star?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, stars

Suppose a receiver records only the electromagnetic signals coming
from a certain star. The vector E (the intensity of the electric field of these signals) oscillates parallel with the plane and horizontal surface of the sea, independent from the propagation direction of the electromagnetic wave. The intensity of any recorded signal is proportional with $E^2$. When the indicator of wavelengths show the value x, the radar receiver records minimum and maximum values. Can I find the angular heights of the the star above sea level, at which the radar receiver records electromagnetic signals of maximum and minimum
intensities?

Comment: Please review your question. It is unclear what you are asking about.